# Javascript Ajax post call exception

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an ajax 'post' call only once when a page loads. My code looks like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.post("amazon/apicalls/ConfirmAndAuthorize.php",{}).done(function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            if (key == 'confirm') {
                var str = JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
                $("#confirm").html(str);
            } else if (key == 'authorize') {
                var str = JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
                alert(str);
                $("#authorize").html(str);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't see anything wrong with the way I'm doing it however I am getting an error when the page loads : `Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`.

What am i forgetting here ?

EDIT:

The answer was a mix between [Artem Gorlachev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040991/javascript-ajax-post-call-exception/44041095#comment75107894_44040991)'s and [Milan Chheda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040991/javascript-ajax-post-call-exception/44041095#comment75107915_44040991)'s comments. It appears JQuery was only included in the page footer. So all that was needed was to wait for the page to load completely.

I achieve that without using JQuery with the methods presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/6346196) to an other question.

Here is what it looks like :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        $.post("amazon/apicalls/ConfirmAndAuthorize.php",{}).done(function(data) {
           ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: or use document ready or insert link to jquery lib before your code

Comment: The error implies `$` is undefined, which means you haven't included jQuery, but then you'd normally see a `$ is undefined` error instead. Is the `$` variable being overridden by another library?

Comment: Have you included JQuery? Seems that is missing. If added, seems its getting overridden.

Comment: Jquery is included. I used a similar code on some other pages with the same `includes`. The only difference being that those other Ajax call where done on some action by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Run in document ready for running only once when a page loads or refresh page

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post("/amazon/apicalls/ConfirmAndAuthorize.php",{}).done(function(data) {.....
     ......
  });
);
.......
</script>
```

Comment: The idea is correct but not the execution. the `(document).ready` could not be used since JQuery was only included in the footer. That had to be done with pure Javascript.

Comment: How about using `$(function() { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a mix between [Artem Gorlachev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040991/javascript-ajax-post-call-exception/44041095#comment75107894_44040991)'s and [Milan Chheda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040991/javascript-ajax-post-call-exception/44041095#comment75107915_44040991)'s answers. It appears JQuery was only included in the page footer. So all that was needed is to wait for the page to load completely.

I achieve that without using JQuery with the methods presented in [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/6346196) to an other question. See edit in OP.

Comment: could you make an edit with the full answer in your OP?